Flutter Geolocator does not update location on Android 14
In my app I have to regularly check location of the device. I do this with geolocator plugin version 12.0.0.
On iOS and Android below 14 everything works fine, but problem is when I test my app on Android 14 (API Level 34). I use Android Simulator and changing location with build-in Extended Controls. When I access device position using .getCurrentPosition() it every time returns position that I set minutes ago.
In app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml I added needed permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
In build.gradle added parameters:
android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true
On testing device, permissions are set to LocationPermission.always.
I've tried to pass forceLocationManager: true in** .getCurrentPosition()**, changed desiredAccuracy and even upgraded Flutter version from 3.19.2 to 3.22.0 but it didn't help.
Is it problem with configuration or plugin itself? I didn't see anything else to set in Android docs

for my case i had issue with the handling permission so by default its working in emulator but when i am testing in real device the location permissions are denied by defaultly then i changed the way of permission requests when opening the app and thats worked for me!!!!
